# ios - validating UIWebView form with JavaScript and getting the form field values in the controller

Tags: ios, ios5, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView and I have a simple form like this:

```
    <form action="http://message/">Your Email: <input id="email" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

and right now there is no JS validation, and the form just gets submitted somewhere and I am not sure how to get the field values. All I have in my controller is this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)aWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{   
    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"message"]) 
    {
        // RIGHT NOW THIS DOESNT WORK...HOW DO I GET IT RIGHT? :)
        NSString *useremail = [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getEmail()"];
        NSLog(useremail);

    }  

    return YES;
}
```

I am not sure how exactly to get the controller to see what the field values and how to validate the field values in the js.

Please advise me how to best accomplish this.

I also tried creating a JavaScript function to simply hit the request url (that is all I really need) but that is not sending the request url:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function test () 
    {
        // Het the params.
        var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
        var email = escape(document.getElementById("email").value);
        var phone = escape(document.getElementById("phone").value);


        var url="http://www.myurl.com?platform=ios&name="+name+"&email="+email+"&phone="+phone;
        alert(url);




        var ajaxObj = createXMLHttp();
        //var url = 'myrequest.php';
        ajaxObj.open("GET", url, true);
        ajaxObj.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            ajaxObj.processRequest();
        }
            ajaxObj.send(null);

            ajaxObj.processRequest = function() 
            {
              if (this.readyState == 4) 
              {
                // got response
              }
            }


        alert("1");
        var req ;

        // Browser compatibility check                  
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {

            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {

                try {
                    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {}
            }

        }


        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", url ,true);
        req.onreadystatechange = function () 
        {
            //document.getElementById('divTxt').innerHTML = "Contents : " + req.responseText;
        }

        req.send(null);  

       return false;
    }
        </script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think `scheme` is the part before the colon. So your form action should point to `message:…` instead of `http://message/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)aWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{   
    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"message"]) 
    {
        NSString *useremail = [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"escape(document.getElementById(\"email\").value);"];
        NSLog(useremail);

    }  

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: can't quite get it to work. Is this supposed to work with conjunction with javascript? If so, how should the js function look like?  I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Try removing the return statement. You can also verify it is actually getting the correct field by trying this `NSString *useremail = [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert(escape(document.getElementById(\"email\").value));"];` this should bring up an alert box with the email value. If it doesn't work, then verify that your document actually has an field named "email"

Comment: Also, I commented out the js since I figured we are going to be hitting the /message/ directly - should I have kept it? I think I am getting it all wrong now :)

Comment: Is the shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate called? Did you use what I suggested in my comment to get the value of the input field? It should just alert you the value on the screen, so we know we are going the correct way. I was referring to the JavaScript return, which I removed in my answer after editing it.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!